# Подсчитать количество онлайн друзей

Tags: count, php, mysql

Здравствуйте помогите подсчитать количество онлайн друзей. Есть такой вывод онлайн друзей.

```
<?php

$frnd_query = mysql_query("SELECT user_one, user_two FROM frnds WHERE user_one='$myrow[id]' OR user_two='$myrow[id]' ORDER BY id DESC ");

while ($run_frnd = mysql_fetch_array($frnd_query)){

  $user_one = $run_frnd['user_one'];
  $user_two = $run_frnd['user_two'];
  if ($user_one == $myrow['id']) {
    $id = $user_two;
  } else{
    $id = $user_one;
  }
  $username = getuser($id, 'username');
  $family = getuser($id,'family');
  $avatar = getuser($id,'avatar');

  //Олнайн офлайн начало
  $userinfo = mysql_query("SELECT lastdate FROM `users` WHERE id='$id'");
  $userinfodat = mysql_fetch_array($userinfo);

  $today = date("U");
  if($userinfodat['lastdate'] + 100 < $today) {
    continue;
  }
?>
Как подсчитать сколько у данного пользователя онлайн друзей?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Немного видоизменил Ваш код:

```
$frnd_query = mysql_query("SELECT user_one, user_two FROM frnds WHERE user_one='$myrow[id]' OR user_two='$myrow[id]' ORDER BY id DESC ");

# Создаём пусто массив для id друзей
$arUser = array();
while ($run_frnd = mysql_fetch_array($frnd_query)){

     $user_one = $run_frnd['user_one'];
     $user_two = $run_frnd['user_two'];

     if ($user_one == $myrow['id']) {
       $id = $user_two;
     } else{
       $id = $user_one;
     }
     # Добавляем в массив для формирования строки запроса.
     $arUser[] = "id = '".$id."'";
  }
# Так и не понял зачем это тут??
  $username = getuser($id, 'username');
  $family = getuser($id,'family');
  $avatar = getuser($id,'avatar');

  //Олнайн офлайн начало
  # Формируем строку условия запроса:

  $im = '(';
  $im .= implode(' or ',$arUser);
  $im .= ')';
  $lastdate = date("U") - 100;
  $userinfo = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` WHERE ".$im." and lastdate < '".$lastdate."'");
  $userinfodat = mysql_fetch_assoc($userinfo);
if($userinfodat['count'] == 0){
   echo 'Друзей онлайн не обнаружено.';
}
else{
  echo 'Друзей онлайн: '.$userinfodat['count'];
};
```

В итоге выгребаем из БД только тех друзей которые онлайн.

Comment: Спасибо большое, заработало.А еще подскажите пожалуйста вот если нет в сети друзей, как написать типа. У вас нет друзей в сети.

Comment: Дополнил ответ. Последние строки.

Comment: @terantul Огромное спасибо вам, а то ломал голову по этому поводу.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте MySQLi вместо MySQL, т.к в новой версии PHP ваши скрипты работать не будут.

Comment: В какой именно новой версии?